# if gravity is just geometry , why is not there anti-gravity in General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, gravity

Is gravity just geometry why is there no anti-gravity or repulsive gravity based on the solution to Einstein's equations?

Comment: Is there a distinction between this question [and your other one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/798141/25301)? Or is the duplication an accident?